# Integral of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z-\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, line-integrals

I'm asked to integrate the function $f(z) = \dfrac{1}{z-\frac{1}{2}}$ over the circle centered at the origin with radius $3$ with positive orientation. I solved the integral with Cauchy's Integral formula and I get that $\displaystyle \int_\gamma\dfrac{1}{z-\frac{1}{2}}\mathrm{d}z$ is $2\pi i$ and then since I'm just starting with these integrals I wanted to check using a parametrization, mainly $\gamma(t) = 3 e^{it} $ for $ 0\leq t \leq 2\pi $ and I end up with this integral $\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{3ie^{it}}{3e^{it}-\frac{1}{2}}\mathrm{d}t$ trying different functions I found that the integral could be solved this way:

$$\begin{aligned} \int_0^{2\pi} \left(Log\left(3e^{it}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)^{\prime} \mathrm{d}t &= Log\left(3e^{it}-\frac{1}{2}\right) \biggr|_0^{2\pi}\\
 &= Log\left(3e^{i2\pi}-\frac{1}{2}\right) - Log\left(3e^{i0}-\frac{1}{2}\right) \\ &= Log\left(3-\frac{1}{2}\right) - Log\left(3-\frac{1}{2}\right) \\ & =0\end{aligned}$$

Can someone explain me this inconsistency please? And also I'm not sure what log I'm supposed to use, the real valued $\ln$ or well the one I assume $Log$.

Comment: $\operatorname{Log}(z)$ is not a primitive of $1/z$ in any set containing the origin. It's not even continuous, so it can't be a primitive.

Comment: $Log(3e^{it}-\frac{1}{2})$ is not continuous on the full circle, so in particular not differentiable hence your use of the fundamental theorem of calculus is incorrect  (however you pick a branch of the multivalued function $Log(3e^{it}-\frac{1}{2})$, you cannot make it continuos on the full circle and you will have a $2\pi$ jump in the imaginary part somewhere and that will account for the correct result with a little care)

Comment: Thanks for your replies (: I understand now.

Comment: Although Wolfram Alpha confuses me I guess it uses the Cauchy Integral Formula [link] (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%283ie%5E%28it%29%29%2F%283e%5E%28it%29-1%2F2%29+from+t%3D0...2pi)
[link] (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%283ie%5E%28it%29%29%2F%283e%5E%28it%29-1%2F2%29)

Comment: If you integrate on a curve that doesn't go around zero (eg on a half period as in the Wolfram link) you can use the antiderivative as it is continuos (and then differentiable) there  with an appropriate choice of the logarithm- technically the image of the curve needs to avoid a ray through the origin (or more generally a simple curve that joins $0$ to $\infty$ as one can concoct a finite curve that intersects every ray but still doesn't go around zero)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the branch of the logarithm $f(z)=\log (z-\frac{1}{2})$:

$$ 0 \le \arg \left(z-\frac{1}{2} \right)< 2\pi,$$ with a branch point at $z_0=1/2$ and a cut from the point $z_0$ along the positive real axis to the point at infinity,

$$\oint \frac{dz}{z-\frac{1}{2}}= \lim_{\theta\uparrow 2\pi} \log\left(3e^{i\theta} - \frac{1}{2}\right)- \log\left(3e^{i\theta}-\frac{1}{2}\right)_{\theta=0} = 2\pi i - 0 = 2\pi i.$$

The function $f(z)$ is holomorphic along the path (but not at the end points).